# Using jQuery, Ajax to get DTO from database and print it at console?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I want to get datas from DB and I'm currently using Spring.
at result there is DTO and if I print it shows like com.shs.s1.coupon.CouponDTO@456bbb4f
and these are the members of DTO and also it has getters/setters.

```
private String couponNum;
private String id;
private long disRate;
private long disPrice;
private String usage;
```

I want to print out couponNum, id and other things at DTO. But it keeps printing out undefined.

```
    function couponSelect() {
        $(".couponSelect").click(function(){
        let couponNum = $(this).attr("title");
        $(".modal-title").html(couponNum);
        $.get("./couponSelect?couponNum="+couponNum, function(result){
            result = result.trim();
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.couponNum);
            console.log(result.id);
            console.log(result.disRate);
        });
    });
}
```

Feel free to comment answers or ideas :)
ALl comments would be nice.

Comment: Not really sure why you use result.trim() if it's an object? Just check before that what console.log outputs from 'result' variable. Maybe you will find something.

Comment: What does `result` look like? If it is just a string of text then you want to return JSON from server

Comment: @Erasus Oh, I think that could be the problem. I thought "com.shs.s1.coupon.CouponDTO@456bbb4f" is a String but it's an object right? I'll retry it thanks:)

Comment: @charlietfl result looks like =
"com.shs.s1.coupon.CouponDTO@456bbb4f"
this

Comment: Convert to json server side. That is just a string with lots of dots in it as far as javascript is concerned

Comment: Can you make a screenshot what you get before result.trim() when you console.log the 'result' variable?

Comment: @charlietfl OK. I'll try it :)

Comment: @Erasus I solved it by making object to JSON thanks for the comment anyway.